# Getting a Joose 2 class in a different src="..." file to work in MSIE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-8, joose

[This page](http://www.shlomifish.org/fc-solve-temp/js-fc-solve/text/), which implements a JavaScript-based online solver for Freecell, does not work in Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 (and possibly below) on my Windows XP 32-bit virtual machine. It works fine in Firefox on the same virtual machine, as well as on Firefox 17.0.2 ESR, Opera and Google Chromium on my x86-64 Mageia Linux 3 system.

To reproduce:

- Type "2" in the deal number.
- Press "Populate".
- Press "Solve".

MSIE 8 throws a fit and claims that "FC_Solve" is not defined, but it is in http://www.shlomifish.org/fc-solve-temp/js/web-fc-solve.js which is included above it and sourced using a script.

I wish I could have dropped support from old versions of MSIE in that page, but I want it to be as idiot-proof as possible, because that was part of the motivation in me creating an online, JavaScript-based, version of [my solver](http://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/), which is written in C. That's because some people asked me to manually solve deals from them because they lacked the know-how to install and run my solver themselves.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It doesn't even work in IE9. Besides that, there is just no good reason to support oldIE with an application like that.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: the problem is that there's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCell_%28Windows%29 which ships as part of Windows and many Windows users with locked-down corporate/military/etc. environments tend to play because they are not allowed to install other games. And such environments may also prevent them from using non-MSIE or newer MSIE browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE<=9 does not support typed arrays (`Uint8Array` etc.) which libfreecellsolver.js seems to use. That most likely prevents it from running on *any* IE not supporting typed arrays.

Besides that, you want `String` instead of `string`:

```
if (!string.prototype.repeat) {
string.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the note regarding the string.prototype thing. It was caused due to a Vim SNAFU (I keep pressing "u" in selection-mode instead of "y", which makes it lowercase.) It is corrected now, but I'm not sure I used .repeat there.

Thanks for the answer regarding typed arrays. I'll investigate and see if emscripten can generate IE-compatible code (or alternatively somehow detect MSIE and tell people to switch to a better browser).